# linux (CLI) download files via shared dropbox (folder`) link without a account

Tags: linux, dropbox

I was thinking to use dropbox to upload my source code of a web-application. For this folder i would create a  shared link. This link i like to use to download all the latest source files on my test server (instead of using s/FTP).

Now i know you can use dropbox with linux by installing their version, but it requires to create account. I **don't want to use a account**, and for sure don't want to use my own account.

Is there anyway to use a shared  (folder) link, and download all the files in that folder command-line, without a account (maybe something like wget) ? There is **no** need for live-syncing, it would be fine to trigger the download with some bash script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with your links being public (which i think is not a good idea) , then you can just create a file with a list of links to your files and then create a bash script to loop over each line of the file get the link with wget

If you want to use authentication, you'll have to register for a Dropbox API key and then create a script (in python,ruby or java etc) to authenticate and get the files.

If you don't have a specific need for dropbox, i'll recommend you use git (or similar). With git you'll just have to create the repository on your server and clone it on your desktop. Then you can just edit your files and push it to the server.... it's so much easier.

Comment: git can also host private sources?

Comment: Yup, git is an open source software. Instead of using a third party code hosting service like github you can just install git on your own server. Many of the cloud hosting services today are using git, for example if you want to deploy your app with heroku.com you can push your app with git to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Rogier, github has become the norm for hosting code. There are other options (Sourceforge, Google Code, Beanstalk) or you can set up a private `git` repository on your own computer.

Somewhere deep in my browser history there's an article about how to do that.

However a little googling turned up http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1652414. Let me know if you can't find some satisfactory instructions on your own of how to set up a `git` repo on your computer.

Comment: I'm aware of GIT. But my initial thought was that for distributing my app to a test server, distribution through dropbox would be pretty easy. No need to check-in. And by manual triggering a sync, i could very quickly deploy a test version.

Comment: @Rogier, have you tried http://ge.tt ? That is a place you can upload something without needing to register a username. I'm not sure what you mean by triggering the download with a bash script. If you uploaded files to ge.tt once, then they wouldn't be live-synced, that seems to match with that part of your question.

Comment: showoff.io is also good for quickly deploying test versions of apps.